# get original permissions of registry key (for users/groups) by command line (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to get original permissions of registry key (for users/groups) by command line (batch)

Example routine:

```
1. get original permissions of key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows [??????]
(this is the part what i want to know)

2. Unblock key:
@echo HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows [1 17] >>c:\unblock.txt
%windir%\system32\regini.exe c:\unblock.txt

3. Modify/delete/add content:
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" /v BlaBla /f

4. Restore Original permissions:
@echo HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows [??????] >>c:\restore.txt
%windir%\system32\regini.exe c:\restore.txt
```

I try with [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe)...

```
SetACL.exe -on "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" -ot reg -actn list > keypermission.txt
```

But the output format is not compatible with regini (out without numbers)

```
current_user\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows

DACL(pseudo_protected):
Administradores   full   allow   container_inherit
CREATOR OWNER   full   allow   container_inherit
Todos   read   allow   container_inherit
SYSTEM   full   allow   container_inherit

SetACL finished successfully.
```

I try with Powershell...

```
Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" | Format-List
```

But the output format is not compatible with regini (out without numbers)

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administradores
Group  : BUILTIN\Administradores
Access : Todos Allow  ReadKey
     CREATOR OWNER Allow  FullControl
     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
     BUILTIN\Administradores Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:BAD:P(A;CI;KR;;;WD)(A;CI;KA;;;CO)(A;CI;KA;;;SY)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)
```

**I need a solution compatible with [regini](http://ss64.com/nt/regini.html) (with numbers):**

```
1  - Administrators Full Access
2  - Administrators Read Access
3  - Administrators Read and Write Access
4  - Administrators Read, Write and Delete Access
5  - Creator Full Access
6  - Creator Read and Write Access
7  - World Full Access
8  - World Read Access
9  - World Read and Write Access
10 - World Read, Write and Delete Access
11 - Power Users Full Access
12 - Power Users Read and Write Access
13 - Power Users Read, Write and Delete Access
14 - System Operators Full Access
15 - System Operators Read and Write Access
16 - System Operators Read, Write and Delete Access
17 - System Full Access
18 - System Read and Write Access
19 - System Read Access
20 - Administrators Read, Write and Execute Access
21 - Interactive User Full Access
22 - Interactive User Read and Write Access
23 - Interactive User Read, Write and Delete Access
```

**Please only command line cmd/batch (not GUI).**

**Update**:

I found a possible solution, but I need to automate in batch:

Export key and found value:

```
reg export "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" export.reg /y && type export.reg | findstr /i "target"
```

Modify "target"

```
???
```

Import key with new value (overwrite old value)

```
reg import export.reg
```

Comment: PowerShell `Get-acl`

Comment: thanks but i need cmd

Comment: You can run powershell commands from batch files ... and what you want is not possible with a pure batch file.

Comment: you could be more specific

Comment: you could go and do some reading :) start with http://ss64.com/ps/get-acl.html